# Range iterator in ES6 similar to Python and Ruby for

Tags: javascript, iterator, ecmascript-6, generator

**Background and Purpose**

For those unaccustomed to Ruby, Ruby supports range literals i.e. `1..4` meaning `1, 2, 3, 4` and `1...4` meaning `1, 2, 3`.  This makes a Ruby `for` loop pretty sweet:

```
for i in 1..3
    doSomething(i)
end
```

It works for non-numeric types and that's pretty cool but out of our scope.

A similarly convenient thing exists in Python, `range`, with some additional features and drawbacks.  `range(1, 4)` evaluates to `[1, 2, 3]`.  You can also provide a step parameter via `range(0, 8, 2)` which evaluates to `[0, 2, 4, 6]`.  There is no option to make the last element inclusive (as far as I know).  `range` calculates its elements the moment it is invoked, but there is also a generator version to avoid unnecessary object creation.  In combination with Python's list construction style, you can do all sorts of cool stuff like `[x*x for x in range(0, 8, 2)]`, which is right on the border of this question's scope.

Now that ES6 has generators and the for-of statement (and most platforms support them), iteration in JavaScript is quite elegant; there is generally only one truly right (or at least best) way to write the loop for your task.  However, if you are iterating over a series of numbers, ES6 offers nothing new.  That's not just in comparison to ES5, but to pretty much every curly-bracket-based language before it.  Python and Ruby (probably other languages I don't know, too) have proven that we can do it better and eliminate stroke-inducing code like:

```
while (i--) {
    sillyMistake(array[i--]);
}

for (
    var sameThing = youHaveWrittenOut;
    verbatimFor >= decades;
    thinkingAboutDetails = !anymore
) {
    neverInspectAboveForErrors();
    assumeLoopVariantIsNotModifiedInHere();
    if (modifyLoopVariant()) {
        quietlyScrewUp() || ensureLoopCondition() && causeInfiniteLoop();
    }
}
```

ES6 for-of, spread operator, and this generator can eliminate all manual loop counter fiddling, unreadable three-part `for`, and smelly loops that initialize arrays.  Please explain how I have succeeded or failed to do so, including any use cases this doesn't cover.

**Code for Review**

```js
const sign = Math.sign;

/**
 * Returns true if arguments are in ascending or descending order, or if all
 * three arguments are equal.  Importantly returns false if only two arguments
 * are equal.
 */
function ord(a, b, c) {
  return sign(a - b) == sign(b - c);
}

/**
 * Three overloads:
 *
 *  range(start, end, step)
 *    yields start, start + step, start + step*2, ..., start + step*n
 *    where start + step*(n + 1) would equal or pass end.
 *    if the sign of step would cause the output to be infinite, e.g.
 *    range(0, 2, -1), range(1, 2, 0), nothing is produced.
 *
 *  range(start, end)
 *    as above, with step implicitly +1 if end > start or -1 if start > end
 *
 *  range(end)
 *    as above, with start implicitly 0
 *
 *  In all cases, end is excluded from the output.
 *  In all other cases, start is included as the first element
 *  For details of how generators and iterators work, see the ES6 standard
 */
function* range(start, end, step) {
  if (end === undefined) {
    [start, end, step] = [0, start, sign(start)];
  } else if (step === undefined) {
    step = sign(end - start) || 1;
  }
  if (!ord(start, start + step, end)) return;
  var i = start;
  do {
    yield i;
    i += step;
  } while (ord(start, i, end));
}

/*
  Use Cases.  Feedback on output method is not necessary.  Insights on use
  cases themselves are welcome.
*/
(function shortFor(ol) {

  for (var i of range(0, 16, 2)) ol.append($("<li>").text(i.toString()));

})($("#short-for .vals"));

(function spreadMap(ol) {

  for (var el of [...range(4)].map(x => x * x)) {
    ol.append($("<li>").text(el.toString()));
  }

})($("#spread-map .vals"));

(function correspondingIndex(ol) {

  var a = [1, 2, 3],
    b = [4, 5, 6];
  for (var i of range(a.length)) a[i] += b[i];

  for (var el of a) ol.append($("<li>").text(el.toString()));

})($("#corresponding-index .vals"));
```

```html
<!-- 
  jQuery is included here to conveniently emit results of test cases;
  the code to be reviewed has no dependencies.
  Feedback on HTML is not necessary.
-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="use-case" id="short-for">
    <h1>Use Case: Less verbose simple for loop</h1>
    <code>for (var i of range(0, 16, 2))</code>
    <p>Values of i:
      <ol class="vals"></ol>
  </div>
  <div class="use-case" id="spread-map">
    <h1>Use Case: Initialize an array without push()</h1>
    <code>[...range(4)].map(x => x*x)</code>
    <p>Array contents:
      <ol class="vals"></ol>
  </div>
  <div class="use-case" id="corresponding-index">
    <h1>Use Case: Add corresponding elements of two arrays</h1>
    <code>
      var a = [1, 2, 3], b = [4, 5, 6];
      for (var i of range(a.length)) a[i] += b[i];
    </code>
    <p>Contents of array a:
      <ol class="vals"></ol>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: +1 for the stroke-inducing code snippet, that was great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers propose replacing

```
yield i;
i += step;
```

with

```
yield start + i*step;
++i;
```

The differences are related to floating point accuracy and performance.  In my original design, the iterator would endlessly spit out the initial value if the step value was too small in comparison, literally `bigNumber + smallNumber === bigNumber`.  In addition, if the increment was not perfectly represented as a float (e.g. `1/3`), error would pile up on the output after many iterations.  By incrementing an integer `i` and multiplying by `step` instead, the iterator would eventually halt and always yield the most appropriate float.

The reason I did not do this initially is that I had integers in mind; while all numbers in JS are supposed to be of interchangeable real number type, it is theoretically possible for a JIT or something to optimize into integer addition if it was always used that way.  Integer math is *way* faster than floating point math, and addition is much faster than multiplying for either type.  Math between a float and an integer is actually the worst, since conversion eats time too.

After some testing, I have concluded that only very few cases (e.g. asm.js style for caller & callee) will allow that optimization to occur and translate into a tangible performance difference, and on many platforms it can just as easily be prevented by using `yield` and `for (... of ...)` or overshadowed by call and return time.  Given time, ES6 implementations may evolve to do better at this, and a special fast integer `range` iterator will be justified, but for the moment, the suggestion of multiplying the step instead of repeatedly adding it is sound.

Finally, the original code fails to produce number sequences of a single element because it returns early if the *second* element will be beyond `end`.  The intent of the early `return` was to make the iterator empty if `step` was the wrong sign.  I tried to combine that idea with invalidating the iterator if you gave it `start` equal to `end`, for e.g. not iterating the indexes of an empty array or string by using `ord`, but that doesn't work.  It's better to spell out both conditions, and the final correct code is:

```
const sign = Math.sign;

function ord(a, b, c) {
  return sign(a - b) == sign(b - c);
}

function* range(start, end, step) {
  if (end === undefined) {
    [start, end, step] = [0, start, sign(start)];
  } else if (step === undefined) {
    step = sign(end - start) || 1;
  } else if (sign(end - start) != sign(step)) {
    return;
  }
  if (start === end) return;

  var i = 0, result;
  do {
    result = start + i*step;
    yield result;
    ++i;
  } while (ord(start, start + i*step, end));
}
```

See above for comments.

Answer (score 3):

> However, if you are iterating over a series of numbers, ES6 offers nothing new.

True, they never put in a range function. But it's pretty easy to build one yourself using the newer APIs. I'm talking about `fill` and `map`. My logic may be off here (not really sure about range's intricacies) but the following should give you a general idea of how it looks like.

```js
function range(start, end, step) {
  var _end = end || start;
  var _start = end ? start : 0;
  var _step = step || 1;
  return Array((_end - _start) / _step).fill(0).map((v, i) => _start + (i * _step));
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(range(10)));
// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

document.write(JSON.stringify(range(1, 11)));
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

document.write(JSON.stringify(range(0, 30, 5)));
// [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```

Above, we just create an empty array with the length needed then we use `map` to fill in the values. What this returns is a regular array of numbers, nothing fancy. However, it makes it possible to use array methods like `forEach`, `map` etc which are more or less equivalent to what you are looking for.

```
Array.apply(null, Array(5));
```

`fill` is relatively new. The older way to do this [was mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10050831/575527). It used the `Array.apply` to force the array to not have empty slots so array methods like `map` can traverse through it.

Now, to your test cases. When we use the approach mentioned above, it's relatively easy to chain array methods one after the other.

```
for (var i of range(0, 16, 2))  ol.append($("<li>").text(i.toString()));

// becomes

range(0, 16, 2).forEach(i => $("<li>").text('' + i).appendTo(ol));

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

for (var el of [...range(4)].map(x => x * x)) {
  ol.append($("<li>").text(el.toString()));
}

// becomes

range(4).map(x => x * x)
        .forEach(i => $('li').text('' + i).appendTo(ol));

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var a = [1, 2, 3],
    b = [4, 5, 6];
for (var i of range(a.length)) a[i] += b[i];
for (var el of a) ol.append($("<li>").text(el.toString()));

// becomes

range(a.length).map(i => a[i] + b[i])
               .forEach(i => $('li').text('' + i).appendTo(ol));
```

As for the other code...

```
for (var i of range(a.length)) a[i] += b[i];
```

It would be best if you returned a new array containing the results of the added `a` and `b`. It's not wrong (hey, it's programming, anything goes), but it will save you from future headaches by not worrying about who mutated `a`. For instance, you need to do another operation with `a` somewhere else but oops! Some operation already mangled the values!

```
ol.append($("<li>").text(i.toString()));

// to

$("<li>").text('' + i).appendTo(ol);
```

Instead of using `containerReference.append(constructedElement)` in jQuery, reverse the order into `constructedElement.appendTo(containerReference)`. It will look more streamlined, avoiding the cluttery parens.

Also, a quick way to turn anything into a string is to prepend a blank string. Since we started a string, JS will start to coerce the succeeding values to a string.

> eliminate all manual loop counter fiddling, unreadable three-part for, and smelly loops that initialize arrays.

Consider using array methods like `forEach`, `map` etc. when running through arrays instead of loops. Most of them provide 3 arguments: current value, current index, and a reference to the original array being traversed. The index is handy for counting and you avoid managing it yourself. The reference to the array traversed is handy especially when you chain together operations and don't want intermediate references to the arrays generated.

```
range(4).map(x => x * x).forEach((v, i, a) => {
  // a = [0, 1, 4, 9], the original array generated by map
});
```

Comment: Agree, this is precisely how I was doing it before spread operator and generators.  I'm sure that 90% of the times I use my `range` will look like `[...range(number)]`.  This is what your `range` returns, right?  Still, I think I prefer *the ability* to have the range as a separate entity, then opt-into having an array.  Two reasons.  One is that a day-one JS coder can look at `[...range(4)]` and know *exactly* what he or she has there, whereas `range` returning an array, they would have to look it up (as a simple thing, likely defined in-project).

Comment: The other is the project this (just the `ord` and `range` functions) came out of, which involved animation and image manipulation.  If I am going to iterate over two regions of two pixel arrays, I am not going to want to make another array of similar size just as a list of indexes.  Animating, the iterator `range` isn't scoped in a snippet-sized loop - it's in the state of an object and it only needs to produce one number per frame.  That's just not what arrays are for.

Comment: @sqykly Yup, my `range` is similar to what you appear to be doing with an array and spread. It's better to add in the purpose of the code in your question so people can orient their answer better. I just went for the simple, general-purpose approach, not a performance-oriented one.

Comment: Side question: is there any reason the array prototype iteration methods (given their explicitly intended generality) were not pulled into a common class (say, `Iterable`) from which `Array` and all the other collections could extend?  I keep needing to write stuff like `[...someSet]` just to get access to `reduce`, when it ought to have a `reduce` of its own.  And you have a point, I will try to come up with a way to better explain the breadth of circumstances I expect this to be useful in.

Comment: @sqykly For your question, I honestly don't know. You might want to ask people over at the [JS channel at StackOverflow chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript).

Comment: Bearing in mind it is just an example, the `_step` variable can be removed if a [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) is used for the argument `site`.